# How does cellForRowAtIndexPath work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multiple-columns

I HAVE READ apple documentation and it's not understandable for such a beginner in `Objective-C` as me. I'm trying to implement multicolumn `UITableView` following this  [link](http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html) example and it just doesn't work so i need to comprehend how `cellForRowAtIndexPath` work, cause for me personally this method seems pretty complicated.

1) What does it return? `UITableViewCell`? But why does it look so odd?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

- What is that? Could you please explain?

2) How does it get called and what is more important how am i to connect it to a certain `UITableView`??? What if i have two `UITableView`'s named `firstTableView` and `secondTableView` and i want them to be different (to perform `cellForRowAtIndexPath` differently)? How am i supposed to link my `UITableViews` to this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the method accepts `NSIndexPath`, not `UITableView`. What am i gonna do?

Comment: Just got to this question. I know this is 6 years old, but anyway... an instance method is described as this: `- (return_type)firstPartOfMethodName:(first_param_type)first_param secondPartOfMethodName:(second_param_type)second_param ...`, where `return_type` is the type of value the method returns, `first_param_type`, `second_param_type`, etc. are the types of the parameters passed to the method, `first_param`, `second_param`, etc. are the actual variables passed to the method and `firstPartOfMethodName:secondPartOfMethodName:...` is the name (or **signature**) of the method.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1) The function returns a cell for a table view yes? So, the returned object is of type `UITableViewCell`. These are the objects that you see in the table's rows. This function basically returns a cell, for a table view.
But you might ask, how the function would know what cell to return for what row, which is answered in the 2nd question

2)`NSIndexPath` is essentially two things-

- Your Section
- Your row

Because your table might be divided to many sections and each with its own rows, this `NSIndexPath` will help you identify precisely which section and which row. They are both integers. If you're a beginner, I would say try with just one section.

It is called if you implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol in your view controller. A simpler way would be to add a `UITableViewController` class. I strongly recommend this because it Apple has some code written for you to easily implement the functions that can describe a table. Anyway, if you choose to implement this protocol yourself, you need to create a `UITableViewCell` object and return it for whatever row. Have a look at its class reference to understand re-usablity because the cells that are displayed in the table view are reused again and again(this is a very efficient design btw).

As for when you have two table views, look at the method. The table view is passed to it, so you should not have a problem with respect to that.

Answer (score 97):

I'll try and break it down (example from [documention](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1))

```
/* 
 *   The cellForRowAtIndexPath takes for argument the tableView (so if the same object
 *   is delegate for several tableViews it can identify which one is asking for a cell),
 *   and an indexPath which determines which row and section the cell is returned for. 
 */ 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     *   This is an important bit, it asks the table view if it has any available cells
     *   already created which it is not using (if they are offScreen), so that it can
     *   reuse them (saving the time of alloc/init/load from xib a new cell ).
     *   The identifier is there to differentiate between different types of cells
     *   (you can display different types of cells in the same table view)
     */

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    /*
     *   If the cell is nil it means no cell was available for reuse and that we should
     *   create a new one.
     */
    if (cell == nil) {

        /* 
         *   Actually create a new cell (with an identifier so that it can be dequeued). 
         */

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    /*
     *   Now that we have a cell we can configure it to display the data corresponding to
     *   this row/section
     */

    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"mainTitleKey"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"secondaryTitleKey"];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[item objectForKey:@"imageKey"] ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    cell.imageView.image = theImage;

    /* Now that the cell is configured we return it to the table view so that it can display it */

    return cell;

}
```

This is a `DataSource` method so it will be called on whichever object has declared itself as the `DataSource` of the `UITableView`. It is called when the table view actually needs to display the cell onscreen, based on the number of rows and sections (which you specify in other DataSource methods).

Comment: Since this thread provides a good deal information, I would like to add one bit of information that might be helpful also. This method is also called if you initiate a reload from some part of your code. e.g. - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

Comment: Shouldn't you put `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` out of the if block? When I put inside it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Basically it's designing your cell, The cellforrowatindexpath is called for each cell and the cell number is found by indexpath.row and section number by indexpath.section . Here you can use a label, button or textfied image  anything that you want which are updated for all rows in the table.
Answer for second question
In cell for row at index path use an if statement

**In Objective C**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if(tableView == firstTableView)
  {
      //code for first table view 
      [cell.contentView addSubview: someView];
  }

  if(tableview == secondTableView)
  {
      //code for secondTableView 
      [cell.contentView addSubview: someView];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

**In Swift 3.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
  let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

  if(tableView == firstTableView)   {
     //code for first table view 
  }

  if(tableview == secondTableView)      {
     //code for secondTableView 
  }

  return cell
}
```

Comment: You should use static for NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier"; This delegate is dynamic, so anything static must be declared correctly.

Comment: But the string does not change it is always going to be "CellIdentifier" each time the cell loads and not something else so cell is reused, Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The string does not change, true. But it will be created many times since the delegate gets called a lot of times. using static ensures the string is created once and gets reused.