# When is cellForRowAtIndexPath method called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When exactly is this method called ? Suppose at a time I have 4 of my tableview cells visible on the screen then for how many cells will this method be called. Also, what if a cell is partially visible, will the method be called for the next cell as well in this case ?

P.S. I am not stuck anywhere, so showing some code doesn't make any sense. Its just a fundamental doubt.

Comment: The `UITableViewDataSource` methods cannot be strictly traced w.r.t their execution order. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called for all the visible rows. this include the partially visible row also. When you scroll the `UITableView` the method is again invoked to update the new rows.

Answer (score 7):

The most simple explanation I can give you is - `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, will call when a cell is about to be shown in the screen of your view controller. So this condition is valid whenever

- Tableview is being reloaded `[tableview reloadData]`, thus every cell will be dequeued/ populated again.
- Every time you scroll and are about to see a new cell. UITableview uses the cell that is going out of the view (visible area), and uses that particular cell to populate new data.
- After `numberOfRows`. If your View Controller has a tableview in the storyboard. This is called in `viewDidLoad` as when the VC inspects a tableview in the storyboard, it will call the mandatory tableview datasource `numberOfRows` first and then it will call `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, that amount of time, the number of cells visible in the screen.

Hope could solve your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
This method will called for the number of time for your number of cell visible.

Suppose current 4 cell visible(row0,row1,row2,row3). it call for 4 time.

when you scroll and now again visible 4 cell like (row2,row3,row4,row5). It again for 4 time for row 2...5. 

So this method will call for each visible cell in tableview every time when your scroll table.
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will be called whenever tableview display the cell.

e.g. if table display 4 cell then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will called 4 times, and as you scroll the tableView this method will called once again.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will called whenever cell will be **created or reuse**.

Answer (score 0):

**Every time** when your cell creates `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method will be called.

Suppose u have 4 cells then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method will call **4 times**.

Answer (score 0):

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be called when you reload tableView and will be called the time for how many rows you return in numberOfRowsInSection method.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is a datasorurce method of tableView.
This is called for all the visible cells initially, though cell is partially visible it will be called.

Consider if you have 10 cells are 5 are visible. Firstly it will be called for 5 cells, and as you scroll down for other cells it will be called for next visible cells.

you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079471/how-does-cellforrowatindexpath-work) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

This Method will called whenever the cell get hit...

i.e.if u have 5 cell will called 5 times the method get hit and while scroll the tableview it will again hit based on the Resuse cell identifier Method...