# UITableViewDataSource not returning the number of rows it should

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewDataSource that return 6 in the func

```
tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)
```

Oddly enough the func

```
tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath)
```

it is executed only 5 times and I have only 5 cells created and one is missing.
This happens only in one orientation. in the other I get 6 cells constructed
It's the first time I see this, why can this happen?

Comment: Only visible cells will be created at first, while you scroll the cells will get re-used/initialised for the remaining ones. Read the doc here]: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrowatindexpath?language=objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's not a bug but a feature. CellForRowAt will be called only they
  need to show a certain index cell.
- Let's say your data source returns 100. These 100 cells won't be
  created in one go. But it will only be created when you scroll them.
- Its happening in one orientation because in that orientation, all of 
  your cells are not visible on the screen.

You can check this post for detailed explanation [When is cellForRowAtIndexPath method called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418359/when-is-cellforrowatindexpath-method-called)